# Conda and Miniconda doesn't include celery in repository

Tags: python, celery, conda

I am trying to install celery using conda in my Miniconda python distribution. I am using PyCharm to manage my project and packages. I have set up the project to use python installed with miniconda as distribution. Trying to install celery from pycharm package manager gives me no results. As well as trying to install conda from command line. Is there a way to install celerey using conda? Is there a way to use both pip and conda in parallerl? Can this be done through PyCharm?I also have python 2.7.10 installed in my windows pc. So I have two python installments in my system one in

```
C:\Python27
```

and one in

```
C:\Miniconda2
```

`conda install celery` return the following

```
Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current win-64 channels matching: celery

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda celery

You may need to install the anaconda-client command line client with

    conda install anaconda-client
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the URL.
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/celery

## conda install -c conda-forge celery=3.1.25

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `celery` is available as a conda package. You can install with pip into a conda environment, yes. But if at all possible you want to try to stick to conda packages.